# Normal subgroups of non-co-hopfian groups (example)

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

We call a group $G$ a non-co-hopfian group, if $G$ admits a non-isomorphic injective group homomorphism from $G$ to itself $i\colon G\hookrightarrow G$.

Consider a finitely presented non-co-hopfian group $G$ with a self-embedding $i$ whose image has finite index $>1$. Define $G_1=i(G), G_2=i(i(G)),\ldots$.

Let $H_1\colon=\text{Core}_G(G_1)$ and $H_2\colon=\text{Core}_{G_1}(G_2)$, where $\text{Core}_G(H)=\cap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg$ . Note that $H_i$ are  normal subgroups of finite index in $G_i$ respectively for $i=1,2$.

My question is:   Is there such a finitely presented non-co-hopfian group $G$ and self-embedding $i$, such that $H_2$ is not a subgroup of $H_1$ (or $H_2$ is not contained in $H_1$) ?

Comment: I really don't understand the vague definition of $G_1,G_2$. Is it the same as "let $G_1,G_2$ be subgroups of finite index of $G$, both isomorphic to $G$, such that $i(G_2)\subset G_1$"? By the way if $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup, it is standard to denote $\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$ as $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your question.  Yes $G_1$ and $G_2$ are defined exactly as what you said.  I have modified the question according to your comments.

Comment: I probably don't understand your question at the moment, because $G=G_2=\mathbf{Z}$, $G_1=2\mathbf{Z}$, $i(n)=2n$ is a trivial example.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your edit. "You get a chain ... " is very unclear. Could you define directly and explicitly $G_1$ and $G_2$? Do you mean $G_1=i(G)$, $G_2=i(i(G))$??

Comment: @YCor  Maybe the the symbol $G_1$ and $G_2$ are confusing.  I have modified the question.  I really start with a chain of subgroups (isomorphic to $G$) of $G$ given by the self-embedding. Then take the successive ``Core''.   I am wondering if the Cores contain ones.

Comment: This is not what you have defined.

Comment: @YCor   Yes I would like to define $G_1=i(G)$ and $G_2=i(i(G))$, ..... Thank you for clarify it.

Comment: But then $G_2\subset G_1$, which implies $\mathrm{Core}_G(G_2)\subset \mathrm{Core}_G(G_1)$...

Comment: @YCor  It is $\text{Core}_{G_1}(G_2)$ instead of $\text{Core}_{G}(G_2)$.

Comment: OK, got it, sorry.

Comment: @YCor  No problem, Thank you for editing  the question.

Comment: Just a quick observation that with this setup, $i(H_1)=H_2$. So, you'd like an example where $i$ doesn't send $H_1$ into itself.

Comment: @MattZaremsky Thanks for your comment.